# Source Directory in XML

Tags: xml, path

I'm trying to get the root directory in XML like so,

```
<SourceDirectory path="root\specified_path" />
```

and I keep getting my current directory starting at root like so,

```
"root/current_directory_path/specified_path"
```

How do I use

```
<SourceDirectory path="root\specified_path" />
```

to get,

```
"root/specified_path"
```

or is there an alternative approach?
I've tried using

```
././specified_path
```

to navigate to the root but that doesn't work either.

Comment: XML and XPath have no notion of directories.  Your question is very unclear.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to use an environment variable to resolve the problem

```
<SourceDirectory path="%env_var%\specified_path" />
```

Comment: Your answer has to do with the application that's processing your XML.  Given that your question hasn't mention what that is, this answer is meaningless.